# Timer, countdown, time

Tags: python, facebook, timer, countdown, repeat

I want, on the def 'UseCaps', to repeat it for 5 seconds. For example, after 5 seconds it repeats the def 'UseCaps' then after 5 seconds it repeats the def again and so on...

Here is the code:

```
def Mobber(self):
    global Mobber

    if Mobber == 0:
        Mobber = 1

        self.EnableMobber() #Jump to EnableMobber   

    else:   
        Mobber = 0
        self.DisableMobber()    

def EnableMobber(self):
    self.MobberButton.SetText("Deactivate")
    self.time.EditLineDelayTime.GetText())
    self.UseCape()

def UseCape(self):
    for i in xrange(player.INVENTORY_PAGE_SIZE*3):
        BraveryCape = player.GetItemIndex(i)
        if BraveryCape == 70038:
            net.SendItemUsePacket(i)
            break
```

I have tried using time.sleep.

Comment: I don't see `time.sleep` anywhere in your code...

Comment: I used it after the break on the last def. but did not work and i removed it.

Comment: If you want help on code you've written, you need to include that code in your question, even if it's not working. That's how debugging works.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a class that has a function that does something every 5 seconds. I used a while loop and modular arithmetic.

```
import time
class The_Class():
    def __init__(self):
        self.counter=0;


    def some_function(self,counter):
        x="I am a function, doing things!"
        if self.counter%2 == 0: # if i is even do uppercase
            return x.upper()
        else:                   #(here self.counter%2 ==1  and is odd so do lowercase)
            return x.lower()

    def a_while_loop(self):
        while 1==1: #so this loop goes on and on because this is always true.
            time.sleep(5) 
            print self.some_function(self.counter)
            self.counter+=1



the_class=The_Class()
the_class.a_while_loop()
```